# Prevent HTML Table Redundancy

Tags: javascript, html

How does one prevent a dynamically created table from spanning multiple times? For example, in the code below, what can I do to make sure the table remains with 3 rows instead of multiplying to 6 rows or more when the button is clicked to populate the table:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         table, td {
         border: 1px solid black;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Click the button to insert new cell(s) at the beginning of the first table row.</p>
      <table id="myTable"></table>
      <br>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <script>
         function myFunction() {
             for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++){//number of rows
                  // Create empty <tr> element, add it to the j position of the table:
                var row = myTable.insertRow(j);

                 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){//number of columns
                        var currentRow = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[j];
                     // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the i positions of the "new" <tr> element
                    var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(i);// should insert 5 (cells or <td>)
                    currentCell.innerHTML = "New cell (" + j + ")(" + i + ")";//the content of all 5 cells, customize later        
                 }
             }
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your function, check for an identifier (probably a class) on your table, then if you can't find it, add it and add your rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way would be to add this to your function:

```js
while(myTable.rows.length)
  myTable.deleteRow(-1);
```

I placed random numbers in the cells of your code so you can see they're changing:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to insert new cell(s) at the beginning of the first table row.</p>

  <table id="myTable">
  </table><br>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {

      while (myTable.rows.length)
        myTable.deleteRow(-1);

      for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) { //number of rows

        // Create empty <tr> element, add it to the j position of the table:
        var row = myTable.insertRow(j);

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //number of columns
          var currentRow = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[j];
          // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the i positions of the "new" <tr> element
          var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(i); //should insert 5 (cells or <td>)
          currentCell.innerHTML = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 100) + "(" + j + ")(" + i + ")"; //the content of all 5 cells, customize l8r

        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```